monaco-editor get invalid tokens line number
trying to get the line number when the content in monaco-editor matches the tokenizer as invalid,then I can use editor.deltaDecorations to customize the UI,
sample of tokenizer in monaco:
        [/0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+\b/, { token: 'constant.numeric' }],
        [/[+-]?\d+(?:(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)?\b/, { token: 'constant.numeric' }],
        [/(?:true|false)\b/, { token: 'constant.boolean' }],
        // strings
        [/["']([^'"\\]|\\.)*$/, 'string.invalid'], // non-teminated string
        { include: '@whitespace' },
        [/\/\/.*$/, { token: 'invalid' }],

expected UI:

However, I didn't find a way to get the line numbers as a list. Does anyone know how to work it out?
